# How to show image links instead of the whole image in DTCoreText

Tags: ios, image, dtcoretext

I'm currently rendering html responses sent from a server in my app but i don't want DTCoreText to render the image (or even make space for the image) instead i just want to provide a link to the image, how may i go about this?

i've tried returning a different view containing a text link through the delegate methods but the problem is that the space reserved by the image still stays there.

E.g Let's say i get a response like this from the server

```
<p>hello there my name is ...</p>
<p>this is what i look like <img src="link" width="300" height="800"></p>
```

That will be rendered as:

```
hello there my name is ....
this is what i look like
```

followed by an 800px empty gap.

Is there a way to also get rid of this gap?

Answer (score 0):

Since no one answered i had to do a work around. i basically used regex and replaced the `<img>`

tags with link tags and when i get the data i replace the tags.

Answer (score 0):

-(void)lazyImageView:(DTLazyImageView *)lazyImageView didChangeImageSize:(CGSize)size

try to change the size of the image ,if u commit the lazyimagedelegate methods